# Rest Call : Post a object (client & server service side)

Tags: restsharp

I have a little problem when implementing a program with the library RestSharp while sending an object.

I implemented a test program (client & server) to test the exchange and I'm stuck on sending an object:

wsDatas.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace EProcess
{
    public class WsQResult
    {
        public string test { get; set; }
    }
}
```

IApi.cs :

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace EProcess
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        WsQResult SendHostInfos(HostInfos hostInfos);
    }
}
```

Api.cs :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace EProcess
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "sendHostInfos")]
        public WsQResult SendHostInfos(HostInfos hostInfos)
        {
            return new WsQResult()
            {
                test = hostInfos.userName
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And the call :

```
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace EProcess
{
    public partial class wMain : Form
    {
        public wMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btTest03_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get host infos
            HostInfos hostInfos = new HostInfos();

            //Send host infos
            var ws = new RestClient("http://localhost:8090");
            var wsQ = new RestRequest("api/sendHostInfos", Method.POST);
            wsQ.AddObject(hostInfos);

            //Send & deserialize result
            RestResponse<WsQResult> wsOut = (RestResponse<WsQResult>)ws.Execute<WsQResult>(wsQ);

            if (wsOut.Data == null)
            {
                label3.Text = "---";
            }
            else
            {
                label3.Text = wsOut.Data.test;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

in Api.cs > public WsQResult SendHostInfos(HostInfos hostInfos), **hostInfos** is always null and wsOut.ResponseStatus is in error but I do not understand why ?

Is the client side, which is poorly implemented or server side (or both)?

Thank you in advance for your assistance